# How to Configure a Stored Procedure to Access a Table in Another Database

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases on the same SQL Server:

Database A

- table 1
- table 2
- sproc x

Database B

- table 3
- table 4
- sproc y
- sproc z

I want to give user1 access to the database, but only through the EXECUTE permission on the sprocs.

- sproc x does a join between table 1 &
  2, and user1 can execute.
- sproc y does a join between tables 3
  & 4, and user1 can execute.
- sproc z does a join between tables 1
  & 4, and user1 is unable to execute,
  unless I grant SELECT permission to
  table 1. Why is this?

I do not want to grant select permission, because this breaks the security model of "only access the database through sprocs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to enable [cross database ownership chaining](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1782) for both databases.

To see if it's enabled:

```
select name, is_db_chaining_on
    from sys.databases
```

To enable the setting:

```
EXEC sp_dboption 'DatabaseA', 'db_chaining', 'true';
GO

EXEC sp_dboption 'DatabaseB', 'db_chaining', 'true';
GO
```

Comment: It wasn't enabled... I enabled for the databases my sprocs where trying to access and it appears to work. Thanks!

Comment: Since I ran into this with some recent databases, a few additional items to check. 1) Make the database owner the same for both databases 2) Make sure the same user / group exists in both databases

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem but in my case the solution was to update the two databases to have the same owner.

If the databases are owned by the same owner you don't need to explicitly turn on ownership chaining (as the owners are one and the same).

Great article on this here: [http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html][1]

You can update the ownership of a database using sp_changedbowner or the "ALTER AUTHORIZATION" statement for more recent version.

Comment: This just happened with some recent databases we created - we forgot to change the owner to SA, and the db_chaining options in the other example didn't work.  As soon as we changed the owner to SA it worked.  Note we still needed to set db_chaining to true